# Row selection dynamically for next page and reverse back in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Anyone please tell me how can i select next consecutive row from first page to second page of my kendo grid and reverse back to the previous page ? Kendo Grid API just only gives me information on 'select' and from there I have no clue at all how to implement my desired selection. What I have now is only selecting the row of the selected/active cell. Any insight/references are also appreciated. So far I haven't came across with any examples or article.

```
var data = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
var arrows = [38,40];
data.table.on("keydown", function (e) {
  if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      data.clearSelection();
      data.select($("#grid_active_cell").closest("tr"));
    },1);
  }
});
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/eSUQO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
var arrows = [38,40];

var navrow_uid; ** add this tracking variable;

data.table.on("keydown", function (e) {
  if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      data.clearSelection();

   // break this up
   // data.select($("#grid_active_cell").closest("tr"));

      // fetch next row uid and compare to tracker
      var nextrow = $("#grid_active_cell").closest("tr");
      var uid = nextrow.data('uid');
      if (navrow_uid == uid ) {
        console.log("last navigable row");
        data.dataSource.page(1+data.dataSource.page());
        // best option here would be to set auto-page flag for databound event handler
      } else {
        data.select(nextrow);
        navrow_uid = uid;
      }
    },1);
  }
});
```

You will want to add a grid data bound handler, and have that check the aut-page flag to see if you need to select first or last row of page.

Comment: truly amazing. It selects rows dynamically when the page changes. Thanks for the help. Any hints for reverse selection? I could only think of remove class for selected ?  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-deselect-row-click

Comment: You could have separate sections for keyCode 38 (up) and keyCode 40(down) and do the same uid tracking.  When no change in uid for the 40 case advance the page and for the 38 case decrease the page.  If you find my response an answer, click on the check mark to make it green and accept as answer.

Comment: Hi my problem is in reverse selection, it was not able to go back to previous page automatically, although I tried to decrease the page number. http://dojo.telerik.com/eSUQO/6